# RIP MavensMate? Stuck while trying to import new project [After API Summer '18]

Tags: mavensmate

Trying to import new project with MM, after signing in MM is acting weird.
First its stuck on this screen for couple of minutes:

[image: 1]

Then its going blank:

[image: 2]

Could that be related to the new API Summer '18?

Comment: [Mavensmate](http://mavensmate.com/) has stopped giving new updates now. So likely that could be the issue. I would suggest you to switch to [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) or Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I am aware about that, I was trying to avoid as long as possible the switch, I'm just wondering if that issue is only me or it's for everyone.

Comment: @alechko , This issue is not reproduced on my side , May be you can try reinstall Mavensmate again

Comment: Thank you @AmitJain, that's the answer I was looking for, now will definitely try to re-install